# rake assets:precomplie is slow (over half an hour)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am running Rails 3.2.3 and when I run

> rake asset:precompile

It takes round 40 minutes to complete.

The follow is in my assets group

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
```

This is running on my local development box. It takes 2,338 seconds which is about 40 minutes. If don't compile locally Heroku times out at round 500 seconds. I have heard people  have issues with 1 to 3 minute compiles. But this is way more. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:** Applcation.js ([gist](https://gist.github.com/2402544))
            Application.css ([gist](https://gist.github.com/2402554))

Comment: is it possible for you to gist the contents of your manifest files that are attempting to be compiled? (eg: application.css / application.js etc ...)

Comment: Have you tried to do this workaround?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537474/rake-assetsprecompile-is-slow

Comment: I am doing this on development box.

Comment: where you able to find a solution Mab879? i have been banging my head on this problem for a while now..

Comment: The solution was have all of the files the need Bootstrap, from Twitter, to be in application.css.scss so that @import 'bootstrap' is only called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was have all of the files the need Bootstrap, from Twitter, to be in `application.css.scss` so that `@import 'bootstrap'` is only called once